# Report Filtering Future Dates to Not Appear - Only Current Due Dates or Overdue Dates Appear

Tags: reporting

salesforce report - How do I make report to show current/overdue due dates, but leave future date fields as blank on report?  Currently, future dates appear and I have to filter future dates when exported to excel.  Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!!. Can you please help to "Edit" and update what you have tried for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

**Two options**

1 - Use row level formula fields to create a new report field that displays as NULL if the `MyDate__c > TODAY()`

1 - Use a custom field on the object (also a formula) that looks like

```
IF (MyDate__c > TODAY(), NULL, MyDate__c)
```